# BigQuery recursively join based on links between 2 ID columns

Tags: sql, recursion, google-bigquery

Given a table representing a many-many join between IDs like the following:

```sql
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id_1, 'a' AS id_2,
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'a'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'b'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'b'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'c'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'c'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'd'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'e'
  UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'f'
)

SELECT * FROM t
```

| id_1 | id_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | c |
| 6 | d |
| 6 | e |
| 7 | f |

I would like to be able recursively join then aggregate rows in order to find each disconnected sub-graph represented by these links - that is each collection of IDs that are linked together:

[image: network diagram]

The desired output for the example above would look something like this:

| id_1_coll | id_2_coll |
| --- | --- |
| 1, 2, 3 | a, b |
| 4, 5 | c |
| 6 | d, e |
| 7 | f |

where each row contains all the other IDs one could reach following the links in the table.

Note that `1` links to `b` even although there is no explicit link row because we can follow the path `1 --> a --> 2 --> b` using the links in the first 3 rows.

Comment: You are looking for a " disjoint-set union (DSU)". For a small amount of rows, this can be solved. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157658/create-a-group-of-linked-items

Answer (score 3):

One potential approach is to remodel the relationships between `id_1` and `id_2` such that we get all the links from `id_1` to itself then use a [recursive common table expression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#recursive_keyword) to traverse all the possible paths between `id_1` values then aggregate (somewhat arbitrarily) to the lowest such value that can be reached from each `id_1`.

### Explanation

Our steps are

1. Remodel the relationship into a series of self-joins for `id_1`
2. Map each `id_1` to the lowest `id_1` that it is linked to via a recursive CTE
3. Aggregate the recursive CTE using the lowest `id_1`s as the `GROUP BY` column and grabbing all the linked `id_1` and `id_2` values via the `ARRAY_AGG()` function

We can use something like this to remodel the relationships into a self join (1.):

```sql
SELECT 
  a.id_1, a.id_2, b.id_1 AS linked_id
FROM t as a
  INNER JOIN t as b 
    ON a.id_2 = b.id_2
WHERE a.id_1 != b.id_1
```

Next - to set up the recursive table expression (2.) we can tweak the query above to also give us the lowest (`LEAST`) of the values for `id_1` at each link then use this as the base iteration:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE base_iter AS (
  SELECT 
    a.id_1, b.id_1 AS linked_id, LEAST(a.id_1, b.id_1) AS lowest_linked_id
  FROM t as a
    INNER JOIN t as b 
    ON a.id_2 = b.id_2
  WHERE a.id_1 != b.id_1
)
```

We can also grab the lowest `id_1` value at this time:

| id_1 | linked_id | lowest_linked_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 4 |

For our recursive loop, we want to maintain an `ARRAY` of linked ids and join each new iteration such that the `id_1` value of the `n+1`th iteration is equal to the `linked_id` value of the `n`th iteration `AND` the nth `linked_id` value is not in the array of previously linked ids.

We can code this as follows:

```sql
recursive_loop AS (
  SELECT id_1, linked_id, lowest_linked_id, [linked_id ] AS linked_ids
  FROM base_iter
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      prev_iter.id_1,  prev_iter.linked_id,
      iter.lowest_linked_id,
      ARRAY_CONCAT(iter.linked_ids, [prev_iter.linked_id])
    FROM base_iter AS prev_iter
    JOIN recursive_loop AS iter
      ON iter.id_1 = prev_iter.linked_id
      AND iter.lowest_linked_id <  prev_iter.lowest_linked_id
      AND prev_iter.linked_id NOT IN UNNEST(iter.linked_ids )      
)
```

Giving us the following results:
|id_1|linked_id|lowest_linked_id|linked_ids|
|----|---------|------------|---|
|3|2|1|[1,2]|
|2|3|1|[1,2,3]|
|4|5|4|[5]|
|1|2|1|[2]|
|5|4|4|[4]|
|2|3|2|[3]|
|2|1|1|[1]|
|3|2|2|[2]|

which we can now link back to the original table for the `id_2` values then aggregate (3.) as shown in the complete query below

### Solution

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id_1, 'a' AS id_2,
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'a'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'b'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'b'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'c'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'c'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'd'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'e'
  UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'f'
),

base_iter AS (
  SELECT 
    a.id_1, b.id_1 AS linked_id, LEAST(a.id_1, b.id_1) AS lowest_linked_id
  FROM t as a
    INNER JOIN t as b 
    ON a.id_2 = b.id_2
  WHERE a.id_1 != b.id_1
),

recursive_loop AS (
  SELECT id_1, linked_id, lowest_linked_id, [linked_id ] AS linked_ids
  FROM base_iter
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      prev_iter.id_1,  prev_iter.linked_id,
      iter.lowest_linked_id,
      ARRAY_CONCAT(iter.linked_ids, [prev_iter.linked_id])
    FROM base_iter AS prev_iter
    JOIN recursive_loop AS iter
      ON iter.id_1 = prev_iter.linked_id
      AND iter.lowest_linked_id <  prev_iter.lowest_linked_id
      AND prev_iter.linked_id NOT IN UNNEST(iter.linked_ids )

      
),

link_back AS (
  SELECT 
    t.id_1, IFNULL(lowest_linked_id, t.id_1) AS lowest_linked_id, t.id_2
  FROM t
    LEFT JOIN recursive_loop
    ON t.id_1 = recursive_loop.id_1
),

by_id_1 AS (
  SELECT 
    id_1,
    MIN(lowest_linked_id) AS grp

  FROM link_back
    GROUP BY 1
),

by_id_2 AS (
  SELECT 
    id_2,
    MIN(lowest_linked_id) AS grp

  FROM link_back
    GROUP BY 1
),

result AS (
  SELECT 
    by_id_1.grp,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id_1 ORDER BY id_1) AS id1_coll,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id_2 ORDER BY id_2) AS id2_coll,
  FROM 
    by_id_1
    INNER JOIN by_id_2
    ON by_id_1.grp = by_id_2.grp
  GROUP BY grp
)

SELECT grp, TO_JSON(id1_coll) AS id1_coll, TO_JSON(id2_coll) AS id2_coll  
FROM result ORDER BY grp
```

Giving us the required output:

| grp | id1_coll | id2_coll |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [1,2,3] | [a,b] |
| 4 | [4,5] | [c] |
| 6 | [6] | [d,e] |
| 7 | [7] | [f] |

---

### Limitations/Issues

Unfortunately this approach is inneficient (we have to traverse every single pathway before aggregating it back together) and fails with the real-world case where we have several million join rows. When trying to execute on this data BigQuery runs up a huge "Slot time consumed" then eventually errors out with:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available for shuffle operations. Consider provisioning more slots, reducing query concurrency, or using more efficient logic in this job.

I hope there might be a better way of doing the recursive join such that pathways can be merged/aggregated as we go (if we have an `id_1` value AND a `linked_id` in already in the list of linked_ids we dont need to check it further).

Comment: My revision was rejected...was pretty sure you meant "FROM result" in your final query

Comment: thanks @JJ32 - not sure how it got rejected :-/ Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Using ROW_NUMBER() the query is as the follow:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id_1, 'a' AS id_2,
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'a'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'b'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'b'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'c'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'c'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'd'
  UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'e'
  UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'f'
),
t1 AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.id_1) n, t.id_1, t.id_2 FROM t
),
t2 AS (
  SELECT n, [n] n_arr, [id_1] arr_1, [id_2] arr_2, id_1, id_2 FROM t1
    WHERE n IN (SELECT MIN(n) FROM t1 GROUP BY id_1)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.n, ARRAY_CONCAT(t2.n_arr, [t1.n]),
    CASE WHEN t1.id_1 NOT IN UNNEST(t2.arr_1)
         THEN ARRAY_CONCAT(t2.arr_1, [t1.id_1])
         ELSE t2.arr_1 END,
    CASE WHEN t1.id_2 NOT IN UNNEST(t2.arr_2)
         THEN ARRAY_CONCAT(t2.arr_2, [t1.id_2])
         ELSE t2.arr_2 END,
    t1.id_1, t1.id_2
    FROM t2 JOIN t1 ON
      t2.n < t1.n AND
      t1.n NOT IN UNNEST(t2.n_arr) AND
      (t2.id_1 = t1.id_1 OR t2.id_2 = t1.id_2) AND
      (t1.id_1 NOT IN UNNEST(t2.arr_1) OR t1.id_2 NOT IN UNNEST(t2.arr_2))
),
t3 AS (
  SELECT
    n,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id_1 ORDER BY id_1) arr_1,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id_2 ORDER BY id_2) arr_2
  FROM t2
  WHERE n IN (SELECT MIN(n) FROM t2 GROUP BY id_1)
  GROUP BY n
)
SELECT n, TO_JSON(arr_1), TO_JSON(arr_2) FROM t3 ORDER BY n
```

- t1 : Append with row numbers.
- t2 : Extract rows matching either id_1 or id_2 by recursive query.
- t3 : Make arrays from id_1 and id_2 with ARRAY_AGG().

However, it may not help your `Limitations/Issues`.

Answer (score 0):

The way this question is phrased makes it appear you want "show me distinct groups from a presorted list, unchained to a previous group". For that, something like this should suffice (assuming  auto-incrementing order/one or both id's move to the next value):

```
SELECT GrpNr,
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CAST(id_1 as STRING), ',') as id_1_coll,
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CAST(id_2 as STRING), ',') as id_2_coll
FROM
(
SELECT id_1, id_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.id_1 <> a.previous_id_1 and a.id_2 <> a.previous_id_2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    OVER (ORDER BY RowNr) as GrpNr
FROM
(
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as RowNr,
  LAG(t.id_1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS previous_id_1,
  LAG(t.id_2, 1) OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS previous_id_2
FROM t
) a
ORDER BY RowNr
) a
GROUP BY GrpNr
ORDER BY GrpNr
```

I don't think this is the question you mean to ask. This seems to be a graph-walking problem as referenced in the other answers, and in the response from @GordonLinoff to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60479528/grouping-groups-with-common-element), which I tested (and presume works for BigQuery).

This can also be done using sequential updates as done by @RomanPekar
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618999/group-all-related-records-in-many-to-many-relationship-sql-graph-connected-comp) (which I also tested). The main consideration seems to be performance. I'd assume dbms have gotten better at recursion since this was posted.

Rolling it up in either case should be fairly easy using String_Agg() as given above or as you have.

I'd be curious to see a more accurate representation of the data. If there is some consistency to how the data is stored/limitations to levels of nesting/other group structures there may be a shortcut approach other than recursion or iterative updates.